# Python: unable to produce the output in list format

Tags: python-2.7

I want to produce the output in a list format but I am failing.

It's taking some login details from a text file:

```
Ip1,username1,pwd1

Ip2,username2,pwd2

Ip3,username3,pwd3

Ip4,username4,pwd4
```

**My Python script:**

```
import os.path

save_path = "C:\Users\Public\Pythonlearn"

input_pwd_file= os.path.join(save_path,'loginfile'+'.txt')

with open(input_pwd_file) as f:

    list = []

    for line in f:

        list.append(line)


    a=list[3] 

print "login details: ",a
```

I am getting below output:

```
login details: Ip4,username4,pwd4
```

But I want it to be like:

```
login details: ['Ip4','username4','pwd4']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `a=list[3]` to `a=list[3].split(',')` and as beruic said, don't name your list 'list'

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are just appending the raw line to the list, instead of parsing it. So, it is expected that the lines in the list is exactly the same as the lines in the file. A simple way to parse the line is by using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and do `line_as_list = line.split(',')`. From there it's just a matter of using the list to make a string from.

Final note: Don't call your list variable `list`. That shadows the built-in constructor to build a list with.